# How to set height of navigation to offset Top Dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, offset

i need to set offset top value dynamically.The dynamic value is 
     height of the navigation.

```
   $("body, html").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $( element ).offset().top - 90
    }, 800);
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/bharathkumar_sriram/pen/eWXjMo)

Comment: `$strong text("body, html")` that will be causing a syntax error.

Comment: Get `$('.navigation').height()` set it to `.offset()`

Comment: can you please explain further what you want to do ? and share relevant code ( html included )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT

after looking at your codepen ( i GUESS i understood what you want ) . i used the navHeight inside the scroll animation

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33030/)

```js
$('.navigation a').on( 'click', function(event) {
 var target  = jQuery( this );
    var element = target.attr('href');
  var navHeight = $("nav").height()

    jQuery('.navigation a').removeClass('active')
    target.addClass('active');

    jQuery("body, html").animate({ 
      scrollTop: jQuery( element ).offset().top - navHeight 
    }, 800);
    return false;

});
```

```css
* {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 font-size: 16px;  
 background: #eee;
 padding-top: 90px;
 font-family: 'Roboto',Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.navigation {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0 10%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 color: #fff;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #363636;
 text-align: center;
}
.navigation a {
 color: inherit;
 margin: 35px 5px;
 line-height: 150%; 
 padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-left: 1px solid #fff;
} 
.navigation a.active { color: yellow; }
.navigation a:first-child { border: 0; }
.box {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 font-size: 14vw;
 padding-top: 100px;
 text-align: center; 
 background: #4CD2DA;
}
.box:nth-child(2) { background: #59DAE2; }
.box:nth-child(3) { background: #4372A6; }
.box:nth-child(4) { background: #D8E0E3; }
.box:nth-child(5) { background: #4B565A; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <nav class="navigation">
  <a class="active" href="#about" title="About">About</a>
  <a href="#work" title="Work">Work</a>
  <a href="#clients" title="Clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#blogs" title="Blogs">Blogs</a>
  <a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
 </nav>
 
 <div id="container">
  <div id="about" class="box">
   Plugin Demo
  </div>
  <div id="work" class="box">
   Work
  </div>
  <div id="clients" class="box">
   Clients
  </div>
  <div id="blogs" class="box">
   Blogs
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="box">
   Contact
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: and ? any explanation what do you want to achieve ? you have a fixed menu that smooth scrolls to anchor. what is the problem here ? anyway EDITED my answer. check it out or see here https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33030/

Comment: @BharathKumar is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: @BharathKumar in that case. don't forget to rate.accept my answer :D thank you